# How Monero pool work?

Tags: monerod, mining-pools, mining

I'm trying to develop monero pool, but have some doubts.

If i make an JSON call 'getblocktemplate' daemon response me with:

{ "id": "0", "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": { "blocktemplate_blob": "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", "difficulty": 982540729, "height": 993231, "prev_hash": "68b84a11dc9406ace9e635918ca03b008f7728b9726b327c1b482a98d81ed830", "reserved_offset": 246, "status": "OK" } }

Now with TCP dump i see other monero pools send to miner this:

{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":null,"result":{"id":"930899847368709","job":{"blob":"0505d982cdcc05dec001feed671cff73ac0525a2651e125bfc925fbe6a39b80eed04431bcd23c5000000000b87dc3128bad43da98ed60b6b5ba13799a6847c1666c1a2c8a9bccae826621305","job_id":"503357152594253","target":"285c8f02"},"status":"OK"}}

And miner response to pools with:

{"method":"submit","params":{"id":"930899847368709","job_id":"503357152594253","nonce":"2b004000","result":"ec94a7b877a8778225a7cc85cf00f4240ee6b75c6607eaa09e66ddc298483801"},"id":1}

Now, my question is, how work all this.

What data is send beetween: monero daemon - pool - miner.

How to calculate shares?

How work difficulty/shares?

Thanks all.

Comment: Please try to narrow the focus of your question. Ask multiple questions instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to figure out how a pool operates by analyzing network traffic, you'd be better off studying the source code of working pools such as:

- [node-monero-pool](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool)
- [Monero Stratum](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum)
- [Miningcore](https://github.com/coinfoundry/mining-core)